# Using JQuery inside React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have used JQuery inside my React functional component to select nodes that have a specific tag + class, just like in CSS, but can I do something similar with React besides the Javascript classic way? For example, if I have an unordered list who has an element with the class "active", I can remove his class like so with JQuery:

```
  $("ul li.active").removeClass("active");
```

With what I have found by now, with React something similar would be:

```
let element = document.getElementByClassName("active")
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(element).classList.remove("active");
```

Obviously the two methods are not equivalent, because in the JQuery one I also specified I want the node to be a `li` with class `active` who is a child of `ul`, so I would probably need to write 2 more lines for it to match the JQuery command.

Is it a shorter or better way of doing this, and also is it OK to use JQuery inside React?

Comment: Ref: [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: " is it OK to use JQuery inside React" Not the best practice, but it won't break your design.

Comment: @Yoshi you're right, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

React discourages the use of direct DOM manipulation. It is fragile and can break when a component is re-rendered.

You should store the selected items in the state and generate class names based on that.

```js
const items = [
  {
    name: "one",
  },
  {
    name: "two",
  },
  {
    name: "three",
  },
];

const App = () => {
  const [selected, updateSelected] = React.useState(["two"]);

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <button
          className={selected.includes(item.name) && "selected"}
          onClick={() => {
            if (selected.includes(item.name))
              updateSelected(selected.filter((name) => name !== item.name));
            else updateSelected([...selected, item.name]);
          }}
        >
          {item.name}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.body);
```

```css
.selected { background: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```